# Nodejs https does not fail on ssl certificate failure

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am using the [https library](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_globalagent) for nodejs to send a https get request using the following code. I get a valid 200 status even though the certificate of the server being tested is expired.

```
https.get(options, this.onResponseCallback.bind(this));
```

The value of options is shown below.

```
{
    protocol: 'https: ',
    slashes: true,
    auth: null,
    host: 'XXXXXXXX',
    port: '443',
    hostname: 'XXXXXXXX',
    hash: null,
    search: 'XXXXXXXX',
    query: 'XXXXXXXX',
    pathname: '/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX',
    path: '/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX?XXXXXXXX',
    href: 'https://XXXXXXXX',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'NodeUptime/3.0(https://github.com/fzaninotto/uptime)'
    },
    rejectUnauthorized: true
}
```

If I hit the same URL in the browser I get the following error.

[image: Firefox]

How do I get nodejs to fail when the cert is expired?

Comment: What makes you sure the cert is expired? That curl error message does NOT say so. Error 60 can be caused by lots of different problems and for expired it says "certificate has expired" NOT "invalid certificate chain". Can you try `openssl s_client` (with only the host:port from the URL, and the same truststore if not default) and what does it say?

Comment: What makes me sure is that I deliberately used an expired cert on our server. This is part of a system that automatically tests our systems and was unable to detect cert expiry failures. So I made a test server with the old certificates.

Comment: Then I can't help, sorry. OpenSSL definitely can and by default does check for expired. I don't know what happens on the way to node.js :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think browser security policy is a bit stricter than what you can do in node.

You can access info about server's certificate by:

```
https.request(options, function(response){
  var cert = response.client.pair.cleartext.getPeerCertificate();
});
```

`.valid_to` is what you are looking for.

More info about [TLS](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html).

Comment: I still think the library should be failing this by default. But this gets me past my problem. thanks